# Why git checkout filename changes its extension?

Tags: git, git-checkout

The git command `git checkout *filename*` does not reset file changes.
Moreover, it changes its extension.

Detailed description:
This is public project repository and those pictures in the folder aren't mine.
I have cloned the project a month ago and haven't touched it.
Today I have pulled repository. After `git pull` I get this strange behaviour:  [terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF41q.jpg)
As you can see i can't reset file changes and the extension switches from `PNG` to `png` (and vice versa).
Is anybody here who can explain me what is going on with my files and git?

Comment: You're on a Windows file system that does case-preservation but case-folding: if there is some existing file named `ABC`, you cannot create a new file named `abc`, because `ABC` and `abc` and for that matter `aBc` and `aBC` and so on all name the *same file*. Other users, on other systems like Linux, *can* create two different files `1.png` vs `1.PNG`, but you can't. Your Git will attempt to compensate for this, but there's only so much it can do about it: if someone committed `1.png` you can't make a different `1.PNG`.

Comment: Thank you for the explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer after deeper googling: i have wrote wrong git command (without `--`).
I am writing here the answer for everyone with the same problem: you should use command:
`git checkout -- *filename*`
instead of
`git checkout *filename*`
Because anything staying after double dashes looks as filenames for git.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting first before `checkout` i.e.

```
git reset head *filename*
git checkout *filename*
```

---

Since you want to discard all files, try doing

```
git reset head .
git checkout .
```

Comment: It gives me the same result [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/OcABH) (`.PNG` -> `.png`).

Comment: Updated the answer, since it's changing the extension, `git checkout` not effective. Try resetting all files at once.